# An exercise with finitely generated graded $R$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the chapter of Free Resolutions in *Using Algebraic Geometry* by Cox, Little, O'Shea. It is my first time dealing with graded modules and therefore
I would really apprecite some help with following exercise:

**Exercise.** 
Suppose that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $M_t$ denotes the set of homogeneous elemets of $M$ of degree $t$.

a) Prove that $M_t$ is finite dimensional vector space over the field $k$ and $M_t={0}$ when $t<< 0$. (use surjective $\varphi$ constructed below

b) Let $\psi:M\to M$ be a graded homomorphism of degree $0.$ Prove that $\psi $ is an isomorphism if and only if $\psi:M_t\to M_t$ is onto for every $t$. Conclude that $\psi$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is onto.

Where the mentioined $\varphi$ is constructed as:

Sppose that $M$ is a graded $R$-module generated by homogeneous elements $f_1,\dots,f_m$ of degrees $d_1,\dots,d_m$. Then we get a graded homomorphism $$\varphi:R(-d_1)\oplus\dots\oplus R(-d_m)\to M$$ which sends the standard basis element $e_i$ to $f_i\in M$. Note that $\varphi$ is onto and that since $e_i$ has degree $d_i$, it follows that $\varphi$ has degree $0.$

**Question 1** Why is $\varphi$ onto? Is it because each generator $f_i$ has corresponding $e_i$ such that $\varphi(e_i)=f_i$?

**Question 2** One part of my other problem is that I am not sure if here $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, with $k$ a fields. But I think it is. And I have no idea how to do the exercise. How can I prove that something is a vector space using a map? I don't know how to do nor a) part nor b)

Comment: If $M$ is a graded $R$-module, then each $M_t$ is a module over $R_0$(why?). Here $R_0=k$ and thus $M_t$ is actually a vector space over $k$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby because from definition of a graded module we have $R_sM_t\subset M_{s+t}$, so we get immediately $R_0M_t\subset M_t$ so it is closed under scalar multiplication .Right? Is this enough? And that is why I wonder how and why would I use the given graded homomorphism... And thanks for commenting!

Comment: Well, you still need to prove that $M_t$ is finite-dimensional over $k$!

Comment: @ThomasShelby ah, yes, of course! thank you